# Extract a part of text from textView and also make that text clickable?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have a string

```
String str =" Hello, @John how's going on"
```

Now I want to know., how to highlight the word `@John` and wanna make it clickable from Textview

Comment: use SpannableString

Comment: oh that's great.. and any idea how to extract only username from the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `clickable span` in a `spannable` string like the following :-

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(" Hello, @John how's going on");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View textView) {
     //perform click operation
   }
   @Override
   public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {

   }
};

ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

yourTv.setText(ss);
yourTv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
yourTv.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

> startIndex - is the index of **J** of word **John** in the full string
>
> endIndex - is the index of **n** of the word **John** in the full string.

&& the **onclick** method will be triggered once john is clicked..

**Edit**

*To extract the username John* u can split the string and get it like this snippet :-

```
 String username = yourString.split("@")[1].split(" ")[0]; // this will extract john
```

Comment: great but bro how can I extract `@John` from the string any idea... I am new

Comment: you want to perform click over john or you want to extract just the word john ? @SurajGiri

Comment: I want to perform click over john and also want to pass john as an argument in further function... for that I want to extract john

Comment: @SurajGiri check the edit .. the last snippet would give you **John**

Answer (score 0):

Here You can Set Your String In text view in your XML file it will not be an issue.

then you can Add the onclick: "clickable" attribute in it and it will work fine

Comment: that will just make whole Textview clickable . What I want is that to extract the username @John and only make that clickable

Answer (score -1):

This will also work with multible mentions.

```js
var str = "Hello, @John how's going on. Greedings to @Bob.";
    var regex = /[@]\S[^. ]*/g;

    var matches = str.match(regex)
    var split = str.split(regex);

    for(var i = 0; i<matches.length;i++){
        document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(split[i]));

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(matches[i]));
        a.title = "my title text";//text you can see onHover
          a.href = "http://example.com/users/"+matches[i].split('@')[1];//link to user
        document.body.appendChild(a);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(split[split.length-1]));
```